# Lists as argument of pandas functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new on python and pandas.
I've a data frame and I want to sort by multiple columns. I've created two lists, one with the columns list and one with sort orders. I want to use these lists into pandas sort_values function

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

d = {'num_sum':[2,3,1,4,5],
     'num_avg':[5,4,3,2,1]}

result = DataFrame(d)

col_list = ['num_sum','num_avg']
sort_order = [True, False]

result = result.sort_values([col_list], ascending=[sort_order])
```

but returns

```
 KeyError: ['num_sum', 'num_avg']
```

How can I pass the two lists as argument of the sort_values function?

Comment: `result.sort_values(col_list, ascending=sort_order) `

Comment: **Note:** you are getting this error because you created nested list of `col_list` and `sort_order` by `[col_list]` and `[sort_order]` because the are initially a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the lists as a variable. This way that you are doing, you are passing a list of lists.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

d = {'num_sum':[2,3,1,4,5],
     'num_avg':[5,4,3,2,1]}

result = DataFrame(d)

col_list = ['num_sum','num_avg']
sort_order = [True, False]

result = result.sort_values(col_list, ascending=sort_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = result.sort_values(col_list, ascending=sort_order)
```

instead of:

```
result = result.sort_values([col_list], ascending=[sort_order])
```